# abelianization of the lamplighter group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, direct-sum, geometric-group-theory

The lamplighter group can be defined by the semidirect product:
$$
L_N=(\mathbb{Z} _N) \wr \mathbb{Z} \cong \bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{N}  \rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z},$$

where $\phi(1)$ "shifts" every element in $\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{N} $ to the right by $1$. I tried to compute the abelianization of the group.

I worked out that $[L_N,L_N]$ is the set of elements in $\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{N}$ whose coordinates sum to $0$.

Then I got  $L_N \big/ [L_N,L_N] = \mathbb{Z}_{N} \oplus \mathbb Z$, is this correct?

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: No that is not correct. Since $G/T(G)$ (torsion subgroup) is infinite cyclic, how could you possibly have two copies of ${\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: Thank you! I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: That seems right. What do you think the homomorphism $G\to G^{\rm ab}$ is explicitly here?